# How long does it take Gmail to train its SPAM filters?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

**tl;dr** *Gmail keeps marking emails as a SPAM even though I have received 100+ of them so far in the past 2,5 month and even though I've clicked "Not a spam" about hundred of times for each and every exactly the same looking email. What is wrong with Gmail's SPAM filter or how long does it usually take Gmail to understand that something is **not** a SPAM?*

---

My local lottery contest is sending me automated email confirmation about each bid. It does as long as I am taking part in it, so right now -- for about 2,5 month. Emails arrives up to ten per week or 1-2 per day. Each and every email has:

- The same sender (both email and name)
- The same title
- Nearly the same body (only date and coupon number changes each time)
- The same signature

Even though I "told" Gmail about 100 times that these kind of emails are not SPAM, it keeps marking them as so and keeps putting them to "Spam" folder. What is wrong with it (or with me) or how long does it need to learn these things?

Note, that I am aware of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4865/21486) and similar and I know how to fix this problem (by introducing some filter etc.). This particular questions comes purely out of my curiosity. If 75+ days of receiving exactly the same email, marked each time, as not a spam wasn't enough to train Gmail's SPAM filters then how can we say that these filters are reliable at all?